# How to compare two dates in Cakephp based on day, month, and year

Tags: cakephp

I have a (hopefully) quick question. I have two dates stored in a database, ['Event]['start_time'] and ['Event']['end_time']. I want to compare the dates to see if they match based on day, month, and year, disregarding the hours, minutes, and seconds they were created. How do I pick out the details of my dates when they're in this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to pull results where the start and end time match? You can do it like this:

```
$results = $this->Event->find('all',array('conditions' => 'DATE(Event.start_time) = DATE(Event.end_time)'));
```

`DATE()` is a MYSQL function that will just return the date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format and drop the time portion.

If you already have the data selected and want to compare it later, you can use the php functions `date()` and `strtotime()` like this:

```
if(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($start_date)) == date('Y-m-d',strtotime($end_date))) {
    //dates are equal
}
```

where `$start_date` is `['Event']['start_time']` and `$end_date` is `['Event']['end_time']`

Comment: That second part was exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!